# Return de función no devuelve nada

Tags: python, funciones

No sé por qué, cuando utilizo return dentro de una función, no me devuelve nada, ni siquiera `None`:

```
def invertir(n):

    cifra3= n % 10
    cifra2= int((n % 100) / 10)
    cifra1= n // 100
    n2= ((cifra3*100)+(cifra2*10)+cifra1)
    
    return n2

invertir (n)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que esperas que haga ese codigo? pq decis que no devuelve nada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí que el `return` está devolviendo algo, lo que sucede es que no estás haciendo nada con el dato retornado.

Prueba así:

```
def invertir(n):
    cifra3= n % 10
    cifra2= int((n % 100) / 10)
    cifra1= n // 100
    n2= ((cifra3*100)+(cifra2*10)+cifra1)
    return n2

n=1325
print(invertir(n))
```

Tu código no devolvía nada porque no le pedías que hiciera nada, ahora le estamos pidiendo que muestre por pantalla lo que retorna tu función.

Por otra parte, tampoco le pasabas nada en la `n`, de hecho deberías obtener el error: `NameError: name 'n' is not defined`

Cuando te encuentres con situaciones similares, plantea siempre un ejemplo mínimo y elemental que reproduzca el fallo. Algo así:

```
def funcion(a):
  return a

funcion(12)
```

La ventaja de hacer esto es que no te distraerás con otras posibles causas y más pronto que tarde darás con la solución: `print(funcion(12))`